# Installing docker on gcp

Tags: docker, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, rancher

Trying to run

```
curl https://releases.rancher.com/install-docker/20.10.sh | sh
```

https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/installation/requirements/installing-docker/

on a Google Compute Engine instance and getting the following error:

**ERROR: '20.10.7' not found amongst apt-cache madison results**

GCP instance is a 2 vcpu 2 gb e2-small

Comment: Do you want to try running an [official docker installation convenience script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script) instead?

Comment: I can do that. I was just following a tutorial on Udemy using the same Ubuntu 20.04 image and I don’t see why it wouldn’t work, just wondered if anyone else came across this issue.

Comment: just created a gcp instance and was able to install docker with the command above

Comment: Could you add the output of `cat /etc/*-release` and full output of running the command?

Comment: May have just been a connection issue on the rancher side since it's working now. But just to answer your question

`root@master:~# cat /etc/*-relea*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hirsute
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.04"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)"
ID=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 21.04"
VERSION_ID="21.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=hirs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GCP console; if you have not created a new Google compute engine as per your tutorial then you can choose Ubuntu after naming it Select a zone and enable HTTP and click ‘Create’.
Enable and create an SSH key for Google compute engine and use the command `sudo -s`(superuser login).
`Sudo apt -get install` [docker.io](https://www.docker.com/) (docker will be installed and it will be ready to go).
Please refer to this [installation documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers).

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.10.7 is not available in this repository:

```
$ apt-cache madison search  docker-ce
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.14~3-0~ubuntu-impish | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.13~3-0~ubuntu-impish | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.12~3-0~ubuntu-impish | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.11~3-0~ubuntu-impish | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:20.10.10~3-0~ubuntu-impish | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish/stable amd64 Packages
```

I fixed the issue downloading 20.10.sh file and changing the line with another version (i.e.: VERSION=20.10.14). It should work.